# Question on $(document).bind()

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, safari

I have a page on iPad. 
How do I get the specific element that was touched instead of the generic container element?

```
$(document).bind("touchstart",function(e){
console.log("touchstart on target : " + e.target.id);
}
```

Comment: What about replacing `touchstart` with `tap`

Comment: Already tried that...does not work..

Comment: `event.target` should actually work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `delegate` instead

```
$(function() {
    $(document).delegate('div', 'click', function(event) {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));

        // To prevent Propagation
        event.stopPropagation()
    });
});
```

in action: http://jsfiddle.net/xem65/

(Using click since I don't have any touch devices nearby atm)

Docs on delegate: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 0):

That seems like it should be working.  Here is a small [test case](http://jsbin.com/ekuxin/5) that logs out the event based off of [http://gregmurray.org/ipad/touch-events.html](http://jsbin.com/ekuxin/5), and it seems to recognize the touchstart happening on the div.  Maybe you could post an example where it is failing?